# Unable to access flash drive from within software in Ubuntu 19.04, able to access through desktop totally fine

Tags: permissions, usb-drive, 19.04

Upgraded to 19.04 today and have run into a problem:

I am able to access my flash drive from my username folder on my desktop and copy and paste back and forth to my Documents, etc. BUT, when I am in Inkscape, Gimp, Scribus, or any other software, I am not able to access at all - It says that I do not have permissions.

I have tried sudo chown user:user media/user/device with no change.

The strangest part is that I can access it and copy and paste when accessing through the user folder on my desktop - I just can't open it from within applications. Anyone know how to fix?